# Download fits files that are in the form of URLs line by line in a txt file using python and saving them iteratively in a folder

Tags: python, html, txt

So my text file contains 20 odd lines,each line having url that has some fits file.I want to read them,download from url and iteratively save them in a uniform manner(using numbers lets say) in a given folder. I want to use python here

I also would like to save the fits files as jpeg in a folder later on again iteratively.

Comment: if you can provide `minimum reproducible code`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.